# Is Synge's world function jointly continuous?

Tags: general-topology, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a geodesically convex pseudo-riemannian manifold. Synge's world function is defined as
$$\begin{align*}
M\times M &\overset{\sigma}{\longrightarrow}\mathbb{R} \\
(p,q)&\mapsto \frac{1}{2}\left\langle \exp_p^{-1}(q), \exp_p^{-1}(q)\right\rangle,
\end{align*}$$
where $\langle,\rangle$ is the metric. By writing the expression for $\sigma$ in normal coordinates one can see that $\sigma$ is smooth separately in each argument and hence separately continuous. But that doesn't directly mean it is continuous wrt. the product topology on $M\times M$. I would guess that since the exponential map is smooth, the world function should also be smooth. But I don't see how inversion of the exponential map can preserve the smoothness. Is $\sigma$ continuous wrt. to the product topology, and if so how do I prove it?